# Read JSON data values

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

For example,
if the data in kafka toipc looks like this

```
{
        "header": {
            "name": "jake"

        },
        "body": {
            "Data":"!#$%&&"
        }
}
```

So how do I read the value "!#$%&&" from my consumer application? I need to process the data once I get that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to consume the data using String Serde, JSON Serde, or define your own.

If you define your own, then you'd call `value.getBody().getData()`, like any other Java Object, where `value` is the argument from mapValues, peek, filter, etc. Kafka Streams DSL

For the others, the answer will depend on what JSON library you're using, but the answer isn't unique to Kafka, so read that library's documentation on parsing strings.

Here's one example of consuming using String Serde - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.1.1-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/JsonToAvroExample.java#L118